# Error: You can only call cameraColorTarget inside the scope of a ScriptableRenderPass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

I am trying to set up a Volumetric Light Scattering as a Custom Renderer Feature in URP by following this [tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/22027819-volumetric-light-scattering-as-a-custom-renderer-feature-in-urp?page=4).

```cs
public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData) {
    renderer.EnqueuePass(m_ScriptablePass);
    m_ScriptablePass.SetCameraColorTarget(renderer.cameraColorTarget);
}
```

Calling SetCameraColorTarget(renderer.cameraColorTarget) results in this error message

```
You can only call cameraColorTarget inside the scope of a ScriptableRenderPass. Otherwise the pipeline camera target texture might have not been created or might have already been disposed.
UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderer:get_cameraColorTarget ()
VolumetricLightScattering:AddRenderPasses (UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderer,UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.RenderingData&) (at Assets/VolumetricLightScattering.cs:139)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

How can I refactor my code to circumvent this error?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue with this [upgrade guide from Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@13.1/manual/upgrade-guide-2022-1.html).

The new code looks like this

```cs
public override void SetupRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, in RenderingData renderingData) {
    m_ScriptablePass.SetCameraColorTarget(renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle);

}

public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData) {
    renderer.EnqueuePass(m_ScriptablePass);
}
```